# Where should I put the prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, phrase-order

Where should the prepositional phrase go in this sentence?

> A student with an adventurous mind like me cannot be happier than this.

or

> A student like me with an adventurous mind cannot be happier than this.

Answer (score 2):

They're both OK, but the second sentence should use commas to set off the second PP to indicate that it's defining what it means to be "like you".

> A student like me, with an adventurous mind, cannot be happier than this.

A better way to write the first sentence would be

> A student with an adventurous mind *like mine* cannot be happier than this.

This makes it clear that it's the adventurous mind that characterizes this set of students.

Answer (score 0):

1. A student with an adventurous mind like me cannot be happier than this.
2. A student like me with an adventurous mind cannot be happier than this.

Both are technically "correct" -- they don't break any rigid rules.

The main problem is that the first version is a hair awkward -- it's not immediately clear what "like me" refers to (though it is reasonably clear after some contemplation).